# Is it possible to create a right-click menu shortcut for a contextual menu?

Tags: macos, shortcuts, bridge

I use Adobe Bridge to make photo contact sheets.
Is it possible to add a keyboard shortcut to the contextual right-click menu?

For example, adding a shortcut through the system preferences works for menu-bar menu-items but does do not work for the contextual menu.

Screenshots macOS System Preferences

[image: Bridge System Preferences Add To Output Document shortcut Option F17]

Screenshot Adobe Bridge Contextual Menu:

[image: Bridge Contextual menu Add To Output Document]